# Should I call ToListAsync() when make a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm not long ago in C# and looking for some best practice how to write a code. Now, I'm working with EF Core and have the following code

```
var details = _dbContext.Details.Where(x => x.Name == "Button");
foreach(var detail in details)
{
   ...
}
```

To better responsive I try to use `ToListAsync()` like

```
var details = await _dbContext.Details.Where(x => x.Name == "Button").ToListAsync();
```

If I'm understood, it should be more efficient way. Should I always use `ToListAsync()` before `foreach`?

The same for deleting. The first one

```
var details = _dbContext.Details.Where(x => x.Id == "Button");
_dbContext.Details.RemoveRange(details);
```

or

```
 var details = await _dbContext.Details.Where(x => x.Id == "Button").ToListAsync();
_dbContext.Details.RemoveRange(details);
```

Which one will be better? So, when I not add `ToListAsync()`, then query will run synchronously?

Comment: The deletion cases are both very bad - you're pulling everything to the client only to delete it. A simple `DELETE FROM Details WHERE Name='Button'` would be a *lot* faster, perhaps even N times faster where N the number or results.`RemoveRange` can only delete records one by one. You can easily create a parameterized query to create the SQL query

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use EF to delete range without plain sql?

Comment: Loading and deleting introduces more serious problems too, like concurrency. What if someone adds a new matching record? It won't be deleted. What if someone else *deletes* a matching record? EF Core will try to delete a missing row.

Comment: Use plain SQL. EF is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. It does only one thing - Map Objects to Relational data. ORMs (any of them) aren't meant for reporting or batch queries.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your comments. What about `ToListAsync`? Should I use it?

Comment: You can use a micro-ORM like Dapper or EF Core's [ExecuteSqlInterpolated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolated?view=efcore-3.1) or `ExecuteSqlRaw` to execute parameterized raw queries

Comment: `ToListAsync` isn't faster. As for more efficient, for some things. It avoids blocking the caller while waiting for the database to respond. This has obvious benefits in a desktop app. In a web site, it's helpful when there's a lot of traffic as blocking threads, thread switching and rescheduling sleeping threads costs in CPU. Async execution in itself though is more expensive and some database providers like MySQL actually *fake it* by using a separate thread to run the query.

Comment: ASP.NET Core already uses a separate thread for each request. Async methods are used to improve throughput and scalability. Fake async methods only waste another thread.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL. How to know if it is not Fake async?

Comment: Npgsql [added real async support](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/121) in 2015. They actually rewrote the provider to offer real async operations

Comment: Thank you, please add this all as an answer then I'll be able to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Returning IEnumerable from an action results in synchronous collection iteration by the serializer. The result is the blocking of calls and a potential for thread pool starvation. To avoid synchronous enumeration, use ToListAsync before returning the enumerable.

Beginning with ASP.NET Core 3.0, IAsyncEnumerable can be used as an alternative to IEnumerable that enumerates asynchronously. For more information, see Controller action return types.

for more information check [ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score -3):

In this case "ToListAsync()" will hinder your performance, just as ToList() would.
The foreach loop is more that capable of handling the "details" variable without the added step of converting it to a list. Doing it asynchronously or synchronously is irrelevant here.

"details" is already a "IQueryable<T>", and turning it into a "List<T>" is unnecessary.

The same applies for your deletion, the conversion is unnecessary.

If you would like to increase your performance there is something you can do;
If the only time you use the variable "details" is for iteration in your foreach loop, you can remove the variable declaration all together and just do this:

```
foreach(var detail in _dbContext.Details.Where(x => x.Name == "Button"))
{
   ...
}
```

Now instead of:

> Create memory -> Read memory from _dbContext.Details... -> Copy that
>   to the newly created memory -> Read newly created memory -> Pass
>   memory to the foreach loop

You simply:

> Read memory from _dbContext.Details... -> Pass memory to the foreach
>   loop

Many examples you will read will have many var assignments. These are simply to break the steps down easier for learners to understand, but will often not be a more performant way of coding.

Comment: On the contrary, the name alone and the fact that `ToListAsync` is available mean this is an EF Core DbContext. [RemoveRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.removerange?view=efcore-3.1) is an EF Core method that marks multiple records for deletion. Async execution makes a real difference in this case.

Comment: No sir. The fact there is an extension that will convert an  IQueryable<T> to a List<T> does not mean that it needs to be or should be converted to a List<T>. This would make a difference in performance while converting it, if it had to be done, but in this case it does not need to be. CPU cycles are wasted doing the conversion one way or another.
I did not understand the RemoveRange() correctly (I have edited my post to account for this), but the same logic applies, converting something to a List<t> that does not need to be converted is a waste of CPU cycles regardless.

Comment: You misunderstand what both `ToList`, `ToListAsync` and even `foreach` do in this case. This is a database query. *Most* of the time is spent executing that query. *Both* `foreach` and `ToList` will have to block for the query to execute and the server to start returning results. Blocking means spinwaiting which means CPU cycles are wasted doing *nothing*. `ToListAsync` won't block though. This has nothing to do with CPU cycles. The equivalent *non*blocking call for IEnumerable would be `AsEnumerableAsync()` which returns an `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Comment: `"details" is already a "IQueryable<T>", and turning it into a "List<T>" is unnecessary.` on the contrary, `IQueryable<T>` represents a LINQ query, not its results. It has to be executed first to produce results. This is done when the query is enumerated, or `ToList`/`ToDictionary` etc are called. With ORMs, the LINQ query gets translated to SQL, executed and the results are returned. ORMs offer async methods to avoid blocking while the query executes